# CSS hover with mouse in translateXY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Thank you for reading my question

```css
.ab {
position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%
}
.logo_img {
  width:100px;
  }
.logo_img:hover {
    -webkit-animation: hvr 0.5s ease-out 1 0s;
    -ms-animation: hvr 0.5s ease-out 1 0s;
    animation: hvr 0.5s ease-out 1 0s;
}
@keyframes hvr {
    0% {  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);transform: translateX(0px); }

    50% { -webkit-transform: translateX(900px);transform: translateX(900px);}
    51% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-900px);transform: translateX(-900px);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0px);transform: translateX(0px);}
}
```

```html
<div class="ab"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="logo_img" /></div>
```

Problem is when mouse goes on it, and image moves, then mouse is not on image and sometimes hover does not work!

Is there any way to do animation like this hover but if mouse is not on image... it keeps going?

Is it possible to user jQuery hover and add class on hover? And delete that class after animation ends?

Comment: `center` is obsolete. And what's the point of `<center/>`? It's not an empty element.

Comment: i use this code in a html site and i cant put all site code here ! i used center for show you how does it works ! if image was in right or left maybe you dont understand...

Comment: is it possible with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var duration = 500;

$('img').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hvr').delay(duration).queue(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hvr');
    $(this).dequeue();
  });
});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/XKRQdA)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a container div for the image, wich always stays in the same place, and put the image inside this div. Then instead of checking, if the mouse is over the image, you can check if it is over the div.

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.logo_img {
  width:100px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50px);
}
#container:hover .logo_img {
    -webkit-animation: hvr 0.5s ease-out 1 0s;
    -ms-animation: hvr 0.5s ease-out 1 0s;
    animation: hvr 0.5s ease-out 1 0s;
}
@keyframes hvr {
    0% {  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);transform: translateX(0px); }

    50% { -webkit-transform: translateX(900px);transform: translateX(900px);}
    51% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-900px);transform: translateX(-900px);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0px);transform: translateX(0px);}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="logo_img">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but if my image was with position:absolute how to fix it?

Comment: another problem with your code : hover is for div ! not image ! i wanna do animation when mouse just goes on image not div !

Comment: @MiLaDTNT Just scale your container div, so the image fits in perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to make animation work without hover then add this `animation-iteration-count` to `infinite`.

```
.logo_img {
    -webkit-animation: hvr 5s ease-out;
    -ms-animation: hvr 5s ease-out;
    animation: hvr 5s ease-out infinite;
}
```

Updated another answer using jQuery,

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").on("mouseenter",function(){
    $(this).addClass("logo_img");
  });
  $("img").on("mouseleave",function(){
    $(this).removeClass("logo_img");
  });
});
```

Comment: That's not what he wants.

Comment: @Bálint Okay was not able to understand his question. 'problem is when mouse goes on it , and image moves then mouse is not on image' I got confused on his this statement.

Comment: no no i want to if mouse goes on it and goes far ... animation goes on and dont stop ...